# Can we convert .apk file in android into supported file for ios,BlackBerry and Windows mobile?

Tags: android, iphone, windows-phone-7, blackberry

I am new to android application development.

I developed one android application and install .apk  of that application in android device,it is working properly.

But my requirement is I wants to run that same application in iPhone ,BlackBerry and Windows Mobile.For that How i install that application in those devices and how to convert that .apk file for that respected devices.

please help me to go forward.

Answer (score 3):

RIM now offers an Android runtime for their BlackBerry Playbook and BlackBerry-10 devices, with some limitations and applications have to be repackaged. See details here: http://developer.blackberry.com/android/documentation/Mastertopic_1849583_11.html

There's no such easy way for porting on other mobile platforms, including the current Java based BlackBerry phones.

Answer (score 1):

Android applications won't run on other mobile devices out of the box. You'll have to write ports of your applications for each device you want to deploy it on.